# React doesn't Redirect properly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-router

I'm trying to check a condition and based on that redirect the page to different paths. i'm using following logic:

```
if (redirectUrl) {
   useEffect(() => { 
   window.location.replace(redirectUrl!);
   });
} else {
   return <Redirect to={'/page'} />;
}
```

but this logic doesn't work properly. if my url is `www.myUrl.com` and the redirect is `www.redirectUrl.com`, this logic redirects me to `www.myUrl.com/www.redirectUrl.com`...it doesn't remove the first url.
how can i properly use this? 
thank you

Comment: Try this window.location.href = "";

Comment: By the way, you should not use condition grammar with hooks.

Comment: @sayalok didn't work.

Comment: @Seven i'm totally new in this. would you please explain more why not

Comment: @faranak777 I recommend you for reading the documentation. https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html#only-call-hooks-at-the-top-level

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not use hooks inside conditions, this is violation of hooks rule you might end up with Stale state inside the component because of this, read this https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html

your code should be like

```
useEffect(() => { 
 if (redirectUrl) {
   window.location.replace(redirectUrl!);

 } else {
   <Redirect to={'/page'} />;
 }
});
```

Also for redirectUrl use full urls including protocols

Comment: thank you while it was useful tip but the issue mentioned in the question wasn't solved by this. I needed to add the full path.

Comment: I also mentioned that in the last line of my answer

Answer (score 0):

use
window.location.href = 'https://www.google.com'
you need to use full url with http protocol.